# Assembly directory doesn't exist:

Tags: xamarin

Im using Xamarin Test cloud for training purposes and Im trying to run my first test. When I try to run the test on the command line I get an error:

Assembly directory doesn't exist: path_to_test_dll

the dll path starts from the c drive.

Ive tried with more than on dll as well.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @mogoli you need point in your directory, not your .dll file. I think you resolved this problem time ago. But I answer for any need this